# Not able to get Debug logs on Console

Tags: spring-boot, logging, log4j2

I have below configuration for my log4j2.xml file in my spring boot application, configuration is working for info, error, warn but I am not able to get logs for Debug on my console can you please suggest where shall I perform the changes to get the logs of debug printed on console.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration monitorInterval="60">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="FUNCTION">project-name</Property>
    </Properties>


    <Appenders>
        <Console name="consoleOut" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p  %-30c{1} [%-10t] %m%n" />
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="FATAL" onMatch="DENY"
                    onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
                <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" />
            </Filters>
        </Console>


        <Console name="consoleError" target="SYSTEM_ERR">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{ISO8601} %-5p  %-30c{1} [%-10t] %m%n" />
            <Filters>
                <ThresholdFilter level="FATAL" />
            </Filters>
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="logFile" fileName="./log/${FUNCTION}.log"
            filePattern="./log/${FUNCTION}.log-%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} %-5p %-30c{1} [%-10t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10" />
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
 
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.myclass" level="DEBUG" />
        <Root level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="logFile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleOut" />
            <AppenderRef ref="consoleError" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

I have also changed my loggging root level to DEBUG but it did not helped either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets walk through how Log4j is going to process a debug event assuming that the event is using a a Logger with a name starting with "com.myclass".

1. There are no global filters so the event bypasses them.
2. The event is assigned to the "com.myclass" LoggerConfig which has a level of DEBUG. Any event with DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, or FATAL will continue. TRACE events will be rejected. So the event will continue to be evaluated.
3. There are no Filters on the Logger so the event will continue to be evaluated.
4. The LoggerConfig has no Appender references so the event will percolate to the root LoggerConfig.
5. The Root LoggerConfig has 3 AppenderRefs, none with Filters so the event will be passed to each of them.
6. The logFile Appender has no Filters so the event will be logged.
7. The consoleOut Appender has two Filters. The first will reject any FATAL events and accept everything else, so DEBUG, INFO, WARN and ERROR events should be logged to the console. The DEBUG filter will be ignored since everything has already been accepted or rejected. In this case the debug event will be logged to system.out.
8. The event is passed to the consoleError appender. It has a Filter using the default match criteria, so FATAL events will continue to be evaluated and all other events rejected. So the debug event will not be logged to system.error.

So according to the above you should be seeing your log event. This indicates to me that you are still using Spring Boot's default logging configuration as [Spring Boot's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html) indicates the default level is info.